# Getting a string from a IO ExitCode monad

Tags: haskell, io, monads, ghc

I'm trying to concatenate a string given as an argument (using `getArgs`) to the haskell program, e.g.:
`"rm " ++ filename ++ " filename2.txt"` which is inside a `main = do` block.

The problem is with the type of filename, and ghc won't compile it, giving an error.

I get an error `Couldn't match expected type [a] against  inferred type IO ExitCode`

the code we're trying to run is:

```
args <- getArgs
let inputfname = head args
system "rm -f "++ inputfname ++ " functions.txt"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `$`:

```
system $ "rm -f "++ inputfname ++ " functions.txt"
```

Or parentheses:

```
system ("rm -f " ++ inputfname ++ " functions.txt")
```

Otherwise you’re trying to run this:

```
(system "rm -f ") ++ inputfname ++ " functions.txt"
```

It fails because `++` wants `[a]` (in this case `String`) but gets `IO ExitCode` (from `system`).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that function application has higher precedence than the `(++)` operator, so it parses as

```
(system "rm -f ") ++ inputfname ++ " functions.txt"
```

while what you meant was

```
system ("rm -f " ++ inputfname ++ " functions.txt")
```

or simply

```
system $ "rm -f " ++ inputfname ++ " functions.txt"
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code works:

```
import System.Process
import System.Environment

main = do
   args <- getArgs
   let inputfname = head args
   system $ "rm -f "++ inputfname ++ " functions.txt"
```

The reasons were explained by other commenters.